# How to start an app with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, tabs, storyboard

I'm trying to make an app for iOS but I'm new to Xcode, and I'm having some problems. In my project file I have a "ViewController.xib", but I need a tabbed application so I created a storyboard and I moved the ViewController from the ".xib" to the Storyboard. In the storyboard I have a Tab Controller with two items, one of them is the ViewController (a photogallery) moved from the ".xib". I've changed the class, I've changed the "Main Interface" with "Main Storyboard" in the project Info, but when I run my application I can't see the Storyboard but the single View Controller, alone. It's like the Storyboard doesn't exist. Forgive my ignorance, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating app checkmark the Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem was another: there were some lines of code that prevented the storyboard to run. By removing those lines (in "AppDelegate.m"), I've solved my problem. Thank you anyway! :D